# Where can I find VGA-to-USB adapters?

Tags: windows-7, usb, display, vga

I'm a laptop user and don't want to buy a monitor anytime soon. I also have a an old stationary computer that I'd like to have a closer look at, and imagine that I could use the laptop screen and some program to render the VGA output from the stationary computer in a window on the desktop of my laptop.
I assume that there exists some kind of USB device that decodes VGA and lets a program route the output to a device context on Windows. Question is, where can I find one (in Europe would be ideal)?

I'm using 64-bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[epiphan VGA2USB](http://www.epiphan.com/products/frame-grabbers/vga2usb/) devices are able to do this.

Comment: Apparently they are. +1.

Comment: You deserve a +1, and deleting my answer... Never knew about this... Far from perfect / not real time which is why I thought it wouldn't be possible - but better than nothing!

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the performance could potentially be lousy...but it's still performance.

Comment: Great, but I see another screen would do for a lower price, even for the most affordable one. But good find!

Comment: Thanks, I found it when I wanted to use my laptop as my primary display for my video game consoles.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Wil in that I don't know of any hardware to accomplish this, at least not just a VGA-USB connector of some kind.  (There are signal converter boxes designed for industrial use, essentially switches for video signal instead of network signal, but that's beyond what you want, I'm sure.)

You might consider just installing remote desktop software to accomplish a similar goal.  Over a LAN, [Radmin](http://www.radmin.com/) is especially fast at redrawing the screen.

Comment: I've used remote desktop before, but doesn't help much if what I wan to do involves pre-OS activities, like installing another OS. Or imagine I don't remember its password.

Comment: @Alejandro - How are you going to do that without some kind of mouse and keyboard?  Or is it in the same room and you just don't want an extra monitor?

Comment: Exactly, I have mouse and keyboard. I imagine it wwill be clumsy, but it can work.